# Perl 6 make code from string

Tags: raku

Is there a way to interpolate a `string` variable into `code`? 
This is what I'm trying to do, and of course it wouldn't even compile.

```
my $cmd = " + 5 ";
my $a = 3;

$a = $a { $cmd };
say $a;
```

Comment: Why is `$cmd` a string in the first place? Shouldn't it be a function?

Comment: Of course, I understand how to do it with a `sub`. The question (probably a silly one) is whether it is possible to do it with a `string`.

Comment: `my $cmd = * + 5;` is better. Then you can do `$a .= $cmd;`

Comment: @BradGilbert, So * is a placeholder?

Comment: You can think of `*` as a placeholder. Here, `* + 5` effectively becomes the code block `{ $_ + 5 }`. Then `$a .= $cmd` runs that code, using the value of `$a` for `$_` and then replacing the original value of `$a` with the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try use [`EVAL`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/EVAL), but note that using `EVAL` is dangerous if you do not have complete control over the string that is going to be evaluated (e.g. consider stuff like `EVAL 'shell "rm -rf *"'`):

```
use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;
my $cmd = " + 5 ";
my $a = 3;
$a = EVAL( EVAL '$a ~ $cmd' ); 
say $a;
```

**Output**:

```
8
```

**Note**:

The line `$a = EVAL( EVAL '$a ~ $cmd' )` incorporates the concatenation operator into the string to be evaluated. If this is not necessary, you could simplify this to `$a = EVAL( $a ~ $cmd )` (as suggested by @W4anD0eR96)